# How can we scrape all header data like name, location, price, rating from inside div class using scrapy and save it to csv file?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

This is the url  https://www.eazydiner.com/goa/restaurants/

```
import scrapy

class WebScraperSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'web_scraper'
    allowed_domains = ['https://www.eazydiner.com']
    start_urls = ['http://https://www.eazydiner.com/goa/restaurants//']

    def parse(self, response):
        'name': response.xpath('//span[@class ="res_name"]/text()').get()
        'location': response.xpath('//span[@class ="res_loc inline-block"]/text()').get()
        'cuisine': response.xpath('//span[@class ="padding-l-10 greyres_cuisine"]/text()').get()
```

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect in your parse function. You are using the syntax for a dictionary without instantiating a dictionary. e.g. 'name': xxx should be name = xxx/

Also, you should add some more details to specifically what issue you are having.

Comment: I have modified the code but still unable to get the answer, I need name, location and price for every restaurant. 'name' : response.xpath('//span[@class="res_name"]/text()').get(),
'title': response.xpath('//span[@class ="res_loc inline-block"]/text()').get(),          
'company' : response.xpath('//span[@class="currency"]/text()').get(),

Comment: c = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Google Chrome',   
})
c.crawl(WebScraperSpider)
c.start()  how to I have these 3 headers in csv file.